# nth character of string to int

Tags: c++

How can I convert nth character of string to number? I have a long number expressed as string and I'd like to make an array of it, where each character would be seperate number. I've tried with followed piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str ="73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203127745063262395783180169848018";
    int ints[1000] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        istringstream ss(str[i]);
        ss >> ints[i];
    }

    cout << ints[9] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    if (isdigit(str[i]))
        ints[i] = str[i] - '0';
```

---

Or maybe:

```
for (string::const_iterator it = str.begin();
     it != str.end(); it++)
         if (isdigit(*it))
             ints[i] = *it - '0';
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you. Could you please explain what does "- '0'" do?

Comment: '0' is 48 in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif), while '1' is 49, so '1' - '0' is a simple math subtraction, `49 - 48`, which results in 1. The same applies to all other digits.

Comment: @user1626154 it converts the ASCII representation of the number to its decimal equivalent. '0' is 48 in decimal, so subtracting '0' gives the decimal value 0, and so on for the other digits.

Comment: @DaV - not just ASCII, any character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char a[2];
a[1] = '\0';
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    a[0] = str[i];
    ints[i] = atoi(a);
}
```

Comment: Use standard functions instead of atoi